# Comparing array entries

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm extremely rusty with my java programming. I'm trying to create a hypothetical company lottery where each  employee can only enter once. Then a name will be randomly generated announcing the winner. I'm not even sure I have some things in the right order at the moment. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. I looked up some things and I believe it to have made it worse.

```
        // instance variables
        final int NUM_PARTIC = 7;  // number of workers participating
        String input;  // holds each name
        int i, j;

        // Create array to hold number of particpants.
        String[] nameArray = new String[NUM_PARTIC];
        // Create a Random class object.
        Random stakes = new Random();

        for(i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++)
        {
            // Prompt participant for name.
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your"
                    + " name into our database:", "Entry", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            nameArray[i] = input;  // Store name in namesArray[]

            // Prompt next participant for name
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name into our"
                    + " database:", "Entry", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            nameArray[i] = input;  // Store name in namesArray[]

            for(j = i + 1; j < nameArray.length; ++j)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, this name is already "
                        + "in our database", "Invalid", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name into our"
                        + " database:", "Entry", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            }

            // Display winner
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The winner for today's raffle "
                    + "is: " + nameArray[i], "Winner",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            // Exit program
            System.exit(0);
```

Comment: You'll need to ask a concrete question before anyone can help you. What is currently going wrong, or what part do you not know how to do?

Comment: Why you using Array? use Set as it won't accept duplicates. And it is easy to iterate over them.

Comment: Hint: Write some functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think you're doing in the code below? It's certainly not searching previous entries. Please speak to yourself and say what you are doing, then say what you want to do, then compare these two answers.

```
for(j = i + 1; j < nameArray.length; ++j)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, this name is already "
                + "in our database", "Invalid", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name into our"
                    + " database:", "Entry", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Besides: just use a `List<String>` instead of `String[]`.

To get a random winner just use `Random` class with it `nextInt(nameArray.length)` method.

Comment: I'll try these out. Totally forgot about using a list for this. It makes perfect sense. Thank you people. I am basically starting programming as I have only done java 1 and 2 about a year ago. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Random` class for randomly selecting a winner from `nameArray`

`Random rand=new Random()`

`int winnerIndex=rand.nextInt(nameArray.length);`

then

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The winner for today's raffle "
                    + "is: " + nameArray[winnerIndex], "Winner",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

All java collections have the `contains` method which searches that collection for the given item.  This would be much preferable to searching an array.

In this case the best would be the Java collection `Set` which allows O(1) (aka very fast searches) for the same element, or just use a `List` if you want to be able to retrieve arbitrary elements like the array.  Either way the method to find an element is done for you.

If you have to do this inside of an Array. You will need to iterate over the array.

```
public static boolean contains(String[] array, String search){
    for (String s: array){
        if (s.equals(search))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using random to select a random value from given values

```
 String randomLotteryWinner() 

{
   String []array={"person1","person2","person3","person4","person5"};

   String Winner=array[(int)(Math.random()*array.length)];

   return Winner;
}
```